# Can I put boards over the drywall ceiling

Tags: ceiling

I want to cover the popcorn ceiling. It has been painted and the ceiling is vaulted. I am thinking about putting up some type of boards such as laminated flooring or a stained pine. Will the ceiling hold that much weight

Comment: This ceiling is only rafters and drywall.

Comment: The ceiling is sloped and the drywall is nailed to the rafters. I will have to check but I believe the rafters are 2x6 or 2x8 on 16' or 24' spacing

Comment: I will have to check

Comment: Please put all relevant information in your question. It doesn't belong down here. Don't forget the span.